Smooth Scrolling
I know variations of this question have been asked before but to my mind none have received an adequate response, so I'm going to try again.
To start, I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on a lenovo ThinkPad T14s with an AMD Ryzen 5 processor. I'm using GNOME version 42.9 and Wayland as my windowing system.
To preempt anyone asking - yes, I do have smooth scrolling in Firefox, Chrome, Evince and several other apps that I don't use and have no interest in. What I want is system-wide smooth scrolling - like what Windows and MacOS have. Also, yes, I've toyed around with Gnome Tweaks and Mouse & Touchpad settings, all to no avail.
I've also tried playing around with libinput. Alas, this doesn't give me the silky smooth scrolling I so desperately crave.
Is there anything that can be done or do I just have to switch back to Windows? The lack of smooth scrolling really is a make-or-break for me, so if Ubuntu can't give it to me I'm out.
